# React/D3 - Adding tooltip to linechart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip to my existing linechart. I tried it in multiple ways but I cant't get it to work

I would like to end up with a tooltip like this: https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_tooltip.html

I tried it multiple ways and now have the following:

```
g.append("g")
      .selectAll("dotDemand")
      .data(dataLine.filter(d => d.valueLine))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return plotDate(d.date) } )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.valueLine) } )
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("fill", "#439DD2")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
               .duration('100')
               .attr("r", 10)
               .attr("stroke", "#000")
               .attr("stroke-width", 5);
               div.transition()
               .duration('50')
               .style("opacity", 0);
          div.html("$" + d3.format(".2f")(d.date))
              .style("left", plotDate(d.valueLine) + 10 + "px")
              .style("top", y(d.date)  + "px");
     })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
               .duration('200')
               .attr("r", 4)
               .attr("fill", "#439DD2")
               .attr("stroke-width", 0);
               //makes div disappear
          div.transition()
              .duration('200')
              .style("opacity", 0);
     });
```

But I'm doing something wrong.

My data looks like this:

```
Date,value
5/31/2022,12
6/1/2022,23
6/2/2022,24
6/3/2022,26
6/4/2022,32
6/5/2022,32
6/6/2022,35
6/6/2022,32
6/7/2022,31
6/8/2022,30
6/8/2022,21
6/10/2022,23
6/11/2022,13
6/12/2022,13
6/13/2022,14
6/14/2022,
6/15/2022,
6/16/2022,
6/17/2022,
6/18/2022,
6/19/2022,
6/20/2022,
6/21/2022,
6/22/2022,
6/23/2022,
6/24/2022,
6/25/2022,
6/26/2022,
6/27/2022,
```

And my full d3 linechart component looks like this:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import csvFile2 from '../../data/testData.csv';

const BasicLinechart = (props) => {

  const [dataLine, setDataLine] = useState([]);
  console.log(csvFile2)
  const { width, height } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataLine.length > 0) {
      drawLineChart();
    } else {
      getCSVDataLine();
    }
  }, [dataLine]);

  // Read in csv
  const getCSVDataLine = async () => {
    const tempData = [];

    await d3.csv(
      csvFile2,
      function (d) {
        tempData.push({
          date: d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y")(d.date),
          valueLine: Number(d.value),
        });
      }
    );
    setDataLine(tempData);
  };

  const drawLineChart = () => {

    const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y"),
      formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%d"),
      formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    // set margins to have enough space for the axis
    var margin = { top: 20, left: 50 };

    // Add X axis in date format: it's a double x-axis with month + year
    var xDate = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataLine, function(d) { return d.date; }))
    .range([ 0, width ])
    
    var xAxisMonth = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xDate)
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    .tickFormat(formatMonth);
    
    // Define 'div' for tooltips
    var div = d3.select("svg")
        .append("div")  // declare the tooltip div 
        .attr("class", "tooltip")              // apply the 'tooltip' class
        .style("opacity", 0);    
  
    // create the chart area
    const svg = d3.select('.svg-basic')
    
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();

    // set base for axes
    var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .attr("class", "legendOrdinal");

    g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 40) + ")")
      .call(xAxisMonth)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("font-size", "12px")
      .attr("stroke", "#595959");

    // styling of the axes (possible later in styling sheet)
    g.selectAll("path")
      .style("stroke", "#595959")

    g.append("g")
      .select(".domain")
      .attr("stroke", "#595959")
      .attr("stroke-width", "6")
      .attr("opacity", ".6");

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataLine, function (d) { return + Math.max(d.valueLine); })])
      .range([height, 10]);
    
    // scale x axis for month and day
    var plotDate = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(dataLine, function (d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([0, width])

    // Styling y
    g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .attr("stroke", "#595959")
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("font-size", "12px")
      .attr("stroke", "#595959");

    // set lines coordinates
    const valueLinePlot = d3.line()
      .x(function (d) { return plotDate(d.date) })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d.valueLine) })
      .curve(d3.curveNatural)

    // Add the line for prediction
    g.append("path")
      .datum(dataLine)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#439DD2")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
      .attr("d", valueLinePlot)
    
      g.append("g")
      .selectAll("dotDemand")
      .data(dataLine.filter(d => d.valueLine))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return plotDate(d.date) } )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.valueLine) } )
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("fill", "#439DD2")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
               .duration('100')
               .attr("r", 10)
               .attr("stroke", "#000")
               .attr("stroke-width", 5);
               div.transition()
               .duration('50')
               .style("opacity", 0);
          div.html("$" + d3.format(".2f")(d.date))
              .style("left", plotDate(d.valueLine) + 10 + "px")
              .style("top", y(d.date)  + "px");
     })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
               .duration('200')
               .attr("r", 4)
               .attr("fill", "#439DD2")
               .attr("stroke-width", 0);
               //makes div disappear
          div.transition()
              .duration('200')
              .style("opacity", 0);
     });

  // text label for the y axis
    g.append("text")      
    .attr("x", '-11%' )
    .attr("y",  '-6%' )
    .style("text-anchor", "right")
    .style("transform", "rotate(-90deg)")
    .text("Total Units (#)")
    .attr("stroke", "#919191")
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("font-size", "10px")

// text label for the x axis
g.append("text")      
    .attr("x", '73%' )
    .attr("y",'70%' )
    .style("text-anchor", "right")
    .text("Date")
    .attr("stroke", "#919191")
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("font-size", "10px")

  }

  return (
    <div >
      <svg className="svg-basic" width="800px" height="600px" />
    </div>
  )

}
export default BasicLinechart;
```

I think that it might be something the referencing to `svg-basic` / `svg`/`g` or something, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: There are so many incoherences in the code you provided that it is difficult to know exactly what you want to achieve. Could you provide a sandbox to reproduce your problem ?

Comment: Just a few hints: you have 2 variables named div, the Date column in your data file has a uppercase 'D', the tooltip must be positionned in absolute mode to set its left and top attribute, the value you put in the left and top attributes are wrong, you cannot format a date with d3.format(".2f"), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create one absolute container first

i saw your code you have defined tooltip two times, first remove those two and this

```
let tooltip = d3
      .select("#tooltipContainer")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("top", 0)
      .style("left", 0)
      .style("display", "none");
```

here is you want to show tooltip div when you hover the dots on line chart then try like this

```
g.append("g")
      .selectAll("dotDemand")
      .data(dataLine.filter(d => d.valueLine))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return plotDate(d.date) } )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.valueLine) } )
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("fill", "#439DD2")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
               .duration('100').attr("r", 10).attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 5);
          tooltip.transition().duration(0).style("display", "block");
          tooltip.html("$" + d3.format(".2f")(d.date))
          .style("left", d.pageX + 10 + "px")
          .style("top", d.pageY+ 10 + "px");
         })
          .on("mouseout", (e) => {
          d3.select(this).transition().attr("r", 4);

           tooltip.transition().duration(0);
           tooltip
                  .style("left", "0px")
                  .style("top", "0px")
                  .style("display", "none");
  })
```

this the code you have to add but **remember you are using the react right**
you have to predefine your jsx elements

Note- don't ever use **`append`** method in react instead of append you have to use **`select , join`** methods
if you use the append method you will get duplicated copy of graph each time when your useEffect and useState changes

i will provide my recent line graph live code to you if you need you can modify according you your needs

here is my codepan javascript code https://codepen.io/codingdarci/pen/ZERpNOG

or you want this in same code in react you can mention me msg i will paste it here

Comment: thank you so much for this! I copied your code and replaced it with bits of mine. It works and more importantly: I now understand the structure way better and caught a lot of switch arounds in my own code. Thank you (this was my first d3 linechart plus the first time working with React so this help is really what I needed)

Comment: Great..!! Appreciated that you have cleared your issue through the codepan source code :-)